# awk code to calculate throughput for some nodes

Tags: awk, ns2

In ns-2 trace files for wireless nodes, I want to calculate throughput for some nodes at once. How to make if condition for specific nodes? The problem is because of "_" between node number. It is very time consuming if I check node one by one because of thousands number of nodes. Here the example of trace files :

```
r 1.092948833 _27_ MAC  --- 171 tcp 1560 [0 1a 19 0] ------- [4194333:0 4194334:0 32 4194334] [37 0] 1 0 [-]
r 1.092948833 _28_ MAC  --- 172 tcp 1560 [0 1a 19 0] ------- [4194333:0 4194334:0 32 4194334] [38 0] 1 0 [-]
r 1.092948833 _25_ MAC  --- 173 tcp 1560 [0 1a 19 0] ------- [4194333:0 4194334:0 32 4194334] [39 0] 1 0 [-]
r 1.092948833 _21_ MAC  --- 174 tcp 1560 [0 1a 19 0] ------- [4194333:0 4194334:0 32 4194334] [40 0] 1 0 [-]
r 1.092948833 _36_ MAC  --- 175 tcp 1560 [0 1a 19 0] ------- [4194333:0 4194334:0 32 4194334] [41 0] 1 0 [-]
r 1.092948833 _29_ MAC  --- 176 tcp 1560 [0 1a 19 0] ------- [4194333:0 4194334:0 32 4194334] [42 0] 1 0 [-]
```

My awk code :

```
action = $1;
sta = $3;
time = $2;
dest = $4;
app = $7;
pkt_size = $8;

    if ( action == "r" && dest == "MAC" && app == "tcp" && time > 1 && ((sta >= "_6_" 
    && sta <= "_30_") || (sta >= "_36_"))) {
        if (start_ == 0) start_ = time;
        if (time > end_) end_ = time;
        sum_ = sum_ + pkt_size;
    }
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Please show sample input and desired output.

Comment: Also please show different variants of data. You are comparing 7th field with `tcp` where as in your data it is `message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be doing something like:

```
if ($1=="r" && $7=="cbr" && $3=="_1_") {
    sec[int($2)]+=$8;
};
```

from the `fil2.awk` in a paper titled ["ns-2 for the impatient"](http://www.manshaei.org/files/HoE-ns2-Mobnet09.pdf).

Though you want to match on different fields, and match on a range of nodes, I'm going to assume you want output similar to:

```
sec[i] throughput[i]
```

from the same paper where `sec[i]` is the second and `throughput[i]` here would be like your sums for each second's worth of packet sizes.

The `sec` array from that snippet is storing packet sums for rounded seconds (rounding provided by `int()`) which means you don't need a `start_` or `end_`.

Since you want to compare multiple nodes, `_` can be added to `FS` to make comparisons easier.  Here's a version of your script modified to produce an output over seconds for the nodes you want to compare binned by seconds:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS="[[:space:]]|_"} # use posix space or underscore for FS

{
action = $1
time = $2
sta = $4   # shifted here because underscores are delimiters
dest = $6
app = $10
pkt_size = $11

if( action == "r" && dest == "MAC" && app == "tcp" &&
    time > 1 && ((sta >= 6 && sta <= 30) || (sta >= 36))) {
        sec[int(time)]+=pkt_size
    }
}
END { for( i in sec ) print i, sec[i] }
```

Notice that the `sta` tests are numeric now instead of string comparisons.  If I put that into an executable awk file called `awko` and run as `awko data` against your data I get:

```
1 9360
```

as the output.

Comment: You're welcome.  The basic issue was with the lexographic comparisons you were making with the `sta` fields.  It's easy to see if you put `_6_`, `_30_` and `_36_` in separate lines of a file and `sort` it.  The output is `_36_`, `_36_`, `_6_` because `6` in the 2nd column is greater than `3` in the 2nd column - the tens groups didn't line up in straight string comparisons.  Rather than lining them up, treating them like numbers lets the range work as you'd expect.